# Prove that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x) = L$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

First, I mentioned that $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x) = L$ if there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $a-x < \delta$ where $|f(a)-f(x)| < \epsilon$.

And that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x) = L$ if there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $x-a < \delta$ where $|f(a)-f(x)| < \epsilon$.

Starting in the forward direction (If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ then $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x) = L$), I began to state that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ means that $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$.

I wanted to split up the inequality to $x-a<\delta$ or $a-x>\delta$.

But after this I'm stuck. The splitting of the equality wouldn't work for $a^-$ and then I wouldn't know how to get the $|f(a)-L|<\epsilon$ part.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Quick note, your definition of one-sided limits are not quite correct. The definition is $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) = L$ if for *every* $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $\vert f(x) - L \vert < \epsilon$ *whenever* $x - a < \delta$, and respectively $a - x < \delta$ for $\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) = L$. Your definition for a two-sided limit is correct.

Take a close look at the definition of limit. Do you know how to prove the forward direction now? We're saying $\vert f(x) - L \vert < \epsilon$  holds when $\vert x - a \vert < \delta$. Note that $\vert x - a \vert < \delta$ is equivalent to $-\delta < x - a < \delta$. Then that means  $\vert f(x) - L \vert < \epsilon$  holds when $x - a < \delta$ and when $a - x < \delta$. So by definition...

Comment: On my worksheet it says that in order for $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) = L$, then $|f(a)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. Do you know how I would show this?

Comment: Are you assuming $\lim_{x\ \to a^+}f(x) = f(a)$?

Comment: Oh, yes, silly me! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

- Your hypothesis for the forward direction is 
  $$\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0\text{ s.t }\forall x\in \mathbb{R},|a-x|\leq\delta\implies|f(a)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon.$$ As $|a-x|\leq\delta$ is equivalent to $-\delta\leq a-x$ and $a-x\leq\delta,$ you can choose for any $\varepsilon>0$ the $\delta$ in the previously assertion, that will satisfy the relations you are looking for.
- For the backward direction it is a little more difficult : your hypothesis are
  $$\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta^{-}>0\text{ s.t }\forall x\in \mathbb{R},a-x\leq\delta\implies|f(a)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon$$ and
  $$\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta^+>0\text{ s.t }\forall x\in \mathbb{R},x-a\leq\delta\implies|f(a)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon.$$ The idea is that, for $\varepsilon>0,$ you take $\delta^-$ and $\delta^+$ given by your hypothesis and then you put $\delta:=\min(\delta^{-},\delta^+).$ I let you check if you can conclude from here !

Comment: If I say: Let $\delta = min(\delta^-, \delta^+)$. Then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$. Thus by the definition of functional limit, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$. Would this be enough?

Comment: I think that you should detail by splitting  $|x-a|<\delta$ and checking how it works, i.e. why this choice of $\delta$ was indeed a good choice.